# How to get file path from user uploaded images, for sending IDs to stripe api not for storing in a database?

Tags: django, django-forms, stripe-payments

I am not too sure if this is possible or not. Using stripes API singing up a user requires an ID picture, front and back, so here is my form for that:

```
class IDuploadForm(forms.Form):
id_front = forms.ImageField()
id_back = forms.ImageField()
```

here is an example of creating a file in stripe from the API:

```
with open("/path/to/a/file.jpg", "rb") as fp:
stripe.File.create(
purpose="dispute_evidence",
file=fp
)
```

My goal is to not have to store the users images on my own server, as they are ID documents, and just be able to send them right to the stripe API, but I have tried this and get errors from stripes side of things

Here is the view I have wrote but does not work(think i am not handling file correctly):

```
class CreateStripeAccount_ID(View):
form = IDuploadForm
template_name = 'id_upload.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = IDuploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        krop = Krop.objects.get(owner=self.request.user)
        str_acc_id = krop.stripe_acc_id
        id_front = form.cleaned_data['id_front']
        id_back = form.cleaned_data['id_back']
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_TEST_SEC_KEY

        #file_id_front = stripe.File.create(
        #   purpose='identity_document',
        #   file=id_front
        #   )
        #file_id_back = stripe.File.create(
        #   purpose='identity_document',
        #   file=id_back
        #   )
        return redirect('home')
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: What error are you getting from the API? If a file size exceeds the `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` setting it will be written to disk

Comment: Are you still having the issue? I think it may be to do with ImageField

Comment: From stripe i get an Invalid Object error. I don't think i am opening the file correctly maybe?? Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: Try using a FileField instead. I think an ImageFile is read to validate it which means you’re passing an “empty” file

Comment: Yes it worked!! I'll look into that more for future, thanks!